# Issue converting date-time to POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, time, timezone, time-series

I'm trying to create date times for every hour of the day for a year with the format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', but if I run the "Original Code" I have posted below it starts at 2014-12-31 16:00:00.  I've found I have to offset it by 8 hours at the start and 7 at the end to get the right range of dates.  I was wondering why this might be?  My goal is to start at 2015-01-01 00:00:00 and end at 2015-12-31 23:00:00.

Code:

```
## problem with conversion, have to offset by 8 hours to start at 2015-01-01 00:00:00
tseries <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-01-01 08:00:00",
                     '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')), 
                      as.POSIXct(strptime("2016-01-01 07:00:00",
                     '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')), by="hour")
tseries <- format.POSIXct(tseries,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df  <- data.frame(VisitDateTime=tseries)
df2 <- df
df2$VisitDateTime<-as.POSIXct(df$VisitDateTime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Original Code:

```
tseries <- seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-01-01 00:00:00",
                      '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')), 
                      as.POSIXct(strptime("2015-12-31 23:00:00",
                      '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')), by="hour")
tseries <- format.POSIXct(tseries,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df  <- data.frame(VisitDateTime=tseries)
df2 <- df
df2$VisitDateTime<-as.POSIXct(df$VisitDateTime,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: This looks like a timezone issue. If you set the timezone to your local timezone when you create the dates, do you still see an offset? For example, using my local time zone: `tseries = seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00", tz="America/Los_Angeles"), as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00", tz="America/Los_Angeles"), by="hour")`.

Comment: what does `Sys.timezone()` return ... ?

Comment: consider converting timezone with `with_tz` function (package lubridate). Here's a good resource on dealing with time on CRAN - https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/28038_1bcb9aa80ca84f27ace07d612872861a.html

Comment: You don't need to do `as.POSIXct(strptime( ... ))`; you can just pass the character and format arguments directly to `as.POSIXct`. Otherwise you're converting to POSIXlt before you convert to POSIXct, which is a waste and a chance to introduce issues like what looks like the timezone one here, likely caused by your local timezone getting introduced when you don't specify one, and then stripped out by POSIXct.

Comment: @eipi10  Thank you, your suggestion totally did the trick!